# DualTouchControls (Jump) in Unity 5 build for iOS does not detect a screen click

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am currently encountering issues with detecting a touch for an iOS test game. I have imported the Cross PlatformInput library provided by Unity and did include the DualTouchControls in my Scene like so:

[image]

When I run the app on my phone I can see the black box but when I press the screen it does not jump my rocket (character). These are the settings of my Jump DualTouchControl:

[image]

And here is the rocket itself with its game environment:

[image]

> What would I like to achieve?
>   I would like to jump the rocket whenever a user taps his screen on his mobile phone. Previously I didn't work with the DualTouchControls because I mainly build it for desktop for testing purposes. It works perfectly on desktop tho using the spacebar.

Hopefully someone can help me out with some tips.

Comment: Could you share your input manager? specifically what the Axis are set for the controls, please?

Comment: @AaronBDC I just drag and dropped the TouchControls onto the canvas.